# wso2 identity server 5.10.0 while setting up with JDBC userstore getting error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to setup `wso2` identity server 5.10.0 getting error `UM_USER_ID not able to insert admin user`.
Is any issue in dbscript

> ID: [-1] [] [2020-04-02 23:32:40,143] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} - DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
>   TID: [-1234] [] [2020-04-02 23:32:44,277] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8377)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:319)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258)
>       ... 30 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while persisting user : admin
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1544)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doAddUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1390)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8366)
>       ... 32 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while updating string values to database.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2558)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1436)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UM_USER_ID', table 'LWSO2_USERSTORE_DB.dbo.UM_USER'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:426)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:372)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:315)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2535)
>       ... 35 more
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2020-04-02 23:32:44,302] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} - Cannot start User Manager Core bundle org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:286)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
>       ... 22 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224)
>       ... 24 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8377)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:319)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:258)
>       ... 30 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while persisting user : admin
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1544)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doAddUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1390)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8366)
>       ... 32 more
>   Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while updating string values to database.
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2558)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1436)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UM_USER_ID', table 'LWSO2_USERSTORE_DB.dbo.UM_USER'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1635)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:426)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:372)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:184)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:159)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:315)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2535)
>       ... 35 more

Comment: It seems you are using old JDBCUserStoreManager. Try switching to UniqueIdJDBCUserStoreManager

Comment: Hope this git issue will provide an insight on this https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7212

Answer (score 2):

From WSO2 IS 5.10.0 onwards, all user store managers have UniqueID included as part of the user store manager name (e.g., UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager). The user store managers that do not have UniqueID as part of the user store manager name are only available for backward compatibility purposes and can only be used if you are migrating from a previous version of WSO2 Identity Server.

The issue you have observed happens due to using the new schema with old JDBCUserStoremanager. Simply changing your userstore manager class to UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager will resolve the issue.

If you are using the old JDBCUserStoreManager, you will have to use the old schema to create the tables. The difference is, UM_USER_ID column is present in the UM_USER table in the new SCHEMA.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/